# Offline features in Stack Exchange App

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

It's not a given that we're always connected to the internet, so *why not include some offline features in the Stack Exchange App?*

Something similar to Gmail app like

[image]

Currently the *favorite questions are missing in the Android App*.  Once they are back, can we have access to favorites in offline mode?  Once  connected to the internet again they could be synced to your device for the latest updates.

I tried to make a sample screen:

[image]

<sup><sub>*This image uses fake data*</sub></sup>

Comment: Why would I be searching Stack if I'm not connected to an internet connection?  What is the relevance of that small, small snippet of questions/answers to what I'm actually looking for *at that instant without connectivity*?

Comment: @Makoto Favourites are used by some people as a library of useful references, for problems they deal with frequently or are dealing with at that very moment. Such users would find having their favourites available offline fairly useful!

Comment: @Makoto There are certain questions in SE that are great for reference.  If I see any such interesting question I used to mark at my favorite and use it for reference.  Whenever I get time I used to go through those answers, I think others too use like I mentioned.  So offering this as offline would be much useful.