# Display Duplicate Chained Questions Sidebar

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, sidebar

Could we consider displaying duplicate questions in a sidebar?

For example if one question is marked as duplicate it gets linked one way but not the other way around.

This can create chains of questions which are all duplicate questions which is confusing.

So click on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values/9121683) it you notice there are 2 questions in a row that are marked as duplicates so technically they should all be duplicates of each other but that is not the case.  They are not displayed in the sidebar.

Comment: Since you just missed existing feature, it's not really a feature request. Retagged.

Comment: As @ShadowWizard said, it already exists, but they are listed along with *any* linked posts, having the duplicates separated from regular linked posts would be a valid feature-request.

Comment: @Cai which kind of exists: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126460/why-doesnt-the-related-question-list-show-that-questions-are-closed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard looks like that is more about showing duplicates (of other posts, not the current) under Related, not Linked.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this is a feature request look at my edit

Comment: @LiamWilliam the duplicate *is* shown in the "Linked" sidebar. The duplicate of the duplicate isn't shown.

Answer (score 2):

Such feature already exists, you somehow missed it:

> [image]

[This is the question in above screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220036/offline-features-in-stack-exchange-app), as you can see both questions under "Linked" section are its duplicates.

Comment: It does list duplicates, but it also lists *any* posts that are linked either to or from the question with no differentiation (the link in your answer for example, now appears as "Linked")

Comment: This doesn't work for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values/9121683 It should show all questions marked as duplicates but it doesn't.

Comment: @LiamWilliam it does [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/9121395?lq=1).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm looking for "Check variable equality against a list of values" and don't see it.

Comment: @LiamWilliam you mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)? Why should it be displayed as duplicate of that other question or linked to it in any way?

Comment: @ShadowWizard click on the duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values/9121683 then click on the next duplicate question.  Which means all the following are dups and linked "Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values" -> "Concise way to compare against multiple values" -> "Check variable equality against a list of values"

Comment: @LiamWilliam so you're talking about the whole "chain", I see.

Comment: @ShadowWizard exactly!!