# The application frequently loses ability to fetch any page until killed and restarted

Tags: bug, android-app

For example, I press a question, and it hangs forever with blank screen. After this, only a complete restart fixes the problem. This is ruining the experience completely since scroll positions are also not saved across restarts.

Also, apparently this application does some network requests on the main thread, or it looks like that. if it's launched with a slow connection, the UI stops responding at all.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5X

  - OS Version: 7.0 (3318108)

Comment: Slow or bumpy connection indeed. Happens to me when below ground, where the signal strength is 0-1 units. (out of 5). That said, all apps behave badly under those conditions, so I'm not sure it can be seen as bug on SE side. (the app got [no offline features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220036/offline-features-in-stack-exchange-app).)

Comment: @ShadowWizard not true, for example Telegram doesn't **freeze UI** when connection quality is low. This is just the result of sloppy coding.

Comment: So not all apps, but many do, e.g. Chrome is also unuseable and freeze when my connection misbehaves like this. Keep in mind Stack Exchange hired a single developer at any point of time to work on their apps. You can't possibly expect from a single person to do something perfect, no matter how good he/she is. It's not "sloppy coding", it's "resources spent elsewhere, not on the app, which gives SE no money back."